# Getting the lastest entry grouped by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a table with stock for products. The problem is that every time there is a stock change, the new value is stored, together with the new Quantity. Example:

```
ProductID | Quantity | LastUpdate
1           123        2019.01.01
2           234        2019.01.01
1           444        2019.01.02
2           222        2019.01.02
```

I therefore need to get the latest stock update for every Product and return this:

```
ProductID | Quantity
1           444
2           222
```

The following SQL works, but is slow.

```
SELECT ProductID, Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT ProductID, Quantity
    FROM Stock
    WHERE LastUpdate 
    IN (SELECT MAX(LastUpdate) FROM Stock GROUP BY ProductID)
)
```

Since the query is slow and supposed to be left joined into another query, I really would like some input on how to do this better.

Is there another way?

Comment: Are you aware of a fact that your query is not correct with respect to your description? It is not equivalent to the solutions provided in the answers.

Comment: @RadimBača please elaborate

Comment: ok, if the second row of your sample data is missing, then your query will return three rows instead of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use analytic functions. [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used in this case.

```
SELECT ProductID, Quantity
FROM (SELECT ProductID, Quantity, row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by LstUpdte desc) as rnum
      FROM Stock
     ) s
WHERE RNUM = 1
```

Or with [`first_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, FIRST_VALUE(Quantity) OVER(partition by ProductID order by LstUpdte desc) as quantuity
FROM Stock
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another option is using `WITH TIES` in concert with `Row_Number()`

**Full Disclosure:**  Vamsi's answer will be a nudge more performant.

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By ProductID Order by LastUpdate Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
ProductID   Quantity    LastUpdate
1           444         2019-01-02
2           222         2019-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

row_number() function might be the most efficient, but the big slow down in your query is the use of the IN statement when used on a subquery, it's a little bit of a tricky one but a join is faster. This query should get what you want and be much faster.

```
SELECT 
     a.ProductID
    ,a.Quantity 
FROM stock as a 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                 ProductID
                ,MAX(LastUpdate) as LastUpdate
            FROM stock 
            GROUP BY ProductID  
            ) b 
ON  a.ProductID = b.ProductId AND 
    a.LastUpdate = b.LastUpdate
```

Answer (score 1):

So you Could use a CTE(Common Table Expression)

Base Data:

```
SELECT  1 AS ProductID
       ,123 AS Quantity
       ,'2019-01-01' as LastUpdate
INTO #table
UNION 
SELECT  2 AS ProductID
       ,234 AS Quantity
       ,'2019-01-01' as LastUpdate
UNION
SELECT  1 AS ProductID
       ,444 AS Quantity
       ,'2019-01-02' as LastUpdate
UNION
SELECT  2 AS ProductID
       ,222 AS Quantity
       ,'2019-01-02' as LastUpdate
```

Here is the code using a Common Table Expression.

```
WITH CTE (ProductID, Quantity, LastUpdate, Rnk)
AS
 (
 SELECT  ProductID
        ,Quantity
        ,LastUpdate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC) AS Rnk
 FROM #table
 )
SELECT ProductID, Quantity, LastUpdate
FROM CTE
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Returns

[image]

You could then Join the CTE to whatever table you need.